# How can I select an element in selenium if my browser opened a new tab after clicking on the last element?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

As I clicked on the price of a sunscreen my browser opened a new tab then I wanted to add the item to the cart but it was not happening. It gives me org. open a.selenium.NoSuchElementException. How can I make my automated software click on it? [The code I tried to add my item to the cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztEef.png)

Answer (score 0):

on browser if you open new tab, you have to switched to the tab. this how i am doing in python .

```
# getting tab ID's
window_count = driver.window_handles

# if opened new tab 
if len(window_count) > 1 :
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```